# why can't I change the value of a var named coma after and if statement

Tags: if-statement, swiftui

I'd like to change the value of comma to true if a string contains a comma
xcode swfitui

```
struct ContentView: View {
        @State var dos = ""
        @State var coma : Bool = false
        
        var body: some View {
            Form {
            TextField("dosis", text: $dos)
                
                if dos.contains(",") == true {
                    
                   coma = true
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put that type code wherever you like in a View. The view expect to show other views, and your `if` is not returning a view. Try this approach where your `if` is in a `modifier`, or a `function`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dos = ""
    @State var coma = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("dosis", text: $dos)
                .onChange(of: dos) { doz in
                    if doz.contains(",") {
                        coma = true
                    }
                    print("--> dos: \(dos)  coma: \(coma)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use: `.onSubmit {...}`